# C++ Plane Sphere Collision Detection

Tags: c++, geometry, collision-detection

I'm attempting to implement Sphere-Plane collision detection in C++. I have a Vector3, Plane and Sphere class.

```
#include "Vector3.h"

#ifndef PLANE_H
#define PLANE_H

class Plane
{
public:
    Plane(Vector3, float);
    Vector3 getNormal() const;
protected:
    float d;
    Vector3 normal;
};

#endif
```

I know the equation for a plane is `Ax + By = Cz + D = 0` which we can simplify to `N.S + d < r` where N is the normal vector of the plane, S is the center of the sphere, r is the radius of the sphere and d is the distance from the origin point. How do I calculate the value of d from my Plane and Sphere?

```
bool Sphere::intersects(const Plane& other) const
{
    // return other.getNormal() * this->currentPosition + other.getDistance() < this->radius;
}
```

Comment: Basically you want to compare the distance of the center of the sphere from the plane with the radius of the sphere. Look for math concerning distance of point from plane. Projecting the point on the plane would also give you a good position to calculate the distance from the plane. Cross product and dot product can help in calculating this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is rather simple formula for point-plane distance with plane equation

`Ax+By+Cz+D=0` ([eq.10 here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html))

```
Distance = (A*x0+B*y0+C*z0+D)/Sqrt(A*A+B*B+C*C)
```

where (x0,y0,z0) are point coordinates. If your plane normal vector (A,B,C) is normalized (unit), then denominator may be omitted.

(A sign of distance usually is not important for intersection purposes)

Comment: If you store `D` in the plane, this answer is more efficient. Good job! Maybe I'll use it.

Comment: Is this value of D is a float and a the parameter to the constructor of my Plane, where I have Plane(const Vector3&, float) ?

Comment: I suggest this is true, but check Plane documentation or constructor body

Comment: I'd suggest to add a constructor `Plane(const Vector3 &normal, const Vector3 &belongingPoint)`, and compute inside `D = -(normal*belongingPoint)`.

Comment: OK, it will be valid D

Comment: The referred source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/distance-between-a-point-and-a-plane-in-3-d/

Answer (score 4):

I needed the same computation in a game I made. This is the minimum distance from a point to a plane:

```
distance = (q - plane.p[0])*plane.normal;
```

Except `distance`, all variables are 3D vectors (I use a simple class I made with operator overload).

`distance`: minimum distance from a point to the plane (scalar).

`q`: the point (3D vector), in your case is the center of the sphere.

`plane.p[0]`: a point (3D vector) belonging to the plane. Note that *any* point belonging to the plane will work.

`plane.normal`: normal to the plane.

The `*` is a dot product between vectors. Can be implemented in 3D as `a*b = a.x*b.x + a.y*b.y + a.z*b.z` and yields a scalar.

### Explanantion

The dot product is defined:

```
a*b = |a| * |b| * cos(angle)
```

or, in our case:

```
a = q - plane.p[0]
a*plane.normal = |a| * |plane.normal| * cos(angle)
```

As `plane.normal` is unitary (`|plane.normal| == 1`):

```
a*plane.normal = |a| * cos(angle)
```

[image]

`a` is the vector from the point `q` to a point in the plane. `angle` is the angle between `a` and the normal to the plane. Then, the cosinus is the projection over the normal, which is the vertical distance from the point to the plane.