# Function to determine when a sphere is touching floor 3d

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, collision-detection

I am trying to get a sphere to make contact with the floor. The spheres radius is 1.0f - I need to work out how to determine the distance between the sphere and the floor.

The Sphere is placed here

```
glm::mat4 mv_matrix_sphere =
    glm::translate(glm::vec3(-2.0f, y, 0.0f)) *
    glm::rotate(-t, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)) *
    glm::rotate(-t, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)) *
    glm::mat4(1.0f);
mySphere.mv_matrix = myGraphics.viewMatrix * mv_matrix_sphere;
mySphere.proj_matrix = myGraphics.proj_matrix;
```

Where y = 20.0f

The sphere will fall and land on the floor at

```
myFloor.mv_matrix = myGraphics.viewMatrix *
    glm::translate(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)) *
    glm::scale(glm::vec3(1000.0f, 0.001f, 1000.0f)) *
    glm::mat4(1.0f);
myFloor.proj_matrix = myGraphics.proj_matrix;
```

The function I need will work out when the Sphere is 1.0f(radius) from the floor so that it collides with it instead of clipping through.

Comment: Defined in the question - It's just a default cube model made thinner and stretched out.

Comment: Does this help? You'll need the normal vector of your plane .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22093749/c-plane-sphere-collision-detection

Comment: Since your floor is a plane perpendicular to the y axis, you only need to check if the difference between the sphere's center and the floor's height is less than or equal to the sphere's radius. But here it looks like the geometry is static, so you might not even have to calculate it.